# Efficient use of ListView on changeCursor and avoid data rebinding?

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

Below is my code for my bindView() for my CursorAdapter.

The whole middle section there is me setting an identifier on one of the images, that will prevent my ImageLoader (a lazy image loader) from rebinding that data to a view that already is bound with the correct data.

I kind of expected ListView to not request bindView, on rows after a notifyDataChanged() if the data for that row stayed the same.

Thinking about the problem, I'm guessing my adapter has to provide a way of determining data equality before skipping, but looking at the source code it getItem and getItemId are not used for this purpose.

Am I doing something unnecessarily hacky, or is this a common optimisation?

```
   @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        int position = cursor.getPosition();

        ImageView thumbnailIv = (ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.thumbnail);

        //Do i really need this to avoid unnecessarily rebinding data to this view??
        Integer cellPosition = (Integer)thumbnailIv.getTag();
        if(cellPosition != null && position == cellPosition.intValue()){
            //skip!
            return;
        }

        thumbnailIv.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));

        Post post = new Post(cursor); //get the data out of the row.

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(post.getThumbnailUrl(), thumbnailIv);
    }
```

Comment: The `ListView` updates all rows if the data changes.

Comment: I know, but with the code I've posted I avoid that, but it seems a bit hacky, and easily avoided, I'm wondering if I'm missing a piece of the puzzle.